# realm and butterknife use together then butterknife not work

Tags: realm, butterknife

This is a part of my project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

aapplication level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reader.hanli.reader"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + rootProject.supportVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + rootProject.supportVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Before i add the realm , butterknife is fine .
And i don't received any exception thrown by butterknife , just a

> NullPointer Exception

on the view.
So what's the problem?Has anyone encountered the seem problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Kotlin, so you should have

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // <-- !!!!
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

And

```
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Is this a way to process annotation in kotlin?But now my project uses all java,so i think it may be other reasons.

Comment: If you're not using Kotlin then why do you have kotlin-android and kotlin-android-extensions???

Comment: It's AndroidStudio auto generate , i tried to use it , but then i give up.May be i will use it in the future ,but not now.Do you have any other ideas?
There is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644096/7271473) , but i don't understand how it worked.

Comment: No. Do what I told you, or remove the Kotlin plugins.

Comment: You are right .I have an unused kotlin file , i tried use kapt but not work,then i delete the file and remove the Kotlin plugins .Now , all fine.thanks very much